# Is there any method to Convert any file, image or video into byte array and vice versa

Tags: android, audio, arrays

I want to know that how can i convert byte array to an audio file,
I'm sending an audio file in the format of byte
but I want it to convert in audio file after receiving

Below is my code:-

```
//Method to convert file to byteArray

    public static byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buff = new byte[10240];
            int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0) {
                baos.write(buff, 0, i);
            }

            return baos.toByteArray(); // be sure to close InputStream in calling function
        }
//on click of send button
mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
                TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
                //   String message = view.getText().toString();
                InputStream inStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hany);
                byte[] message = null;
                try {
                    message = convertStreamToByteArray(inStream);

                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sendMessage(message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Define _"audio file"_. Which container and codec are you aiming to use?

Comment: I had save my audio file in raw folder
Act i'm trying to send audio file via bluetooth,